# Python add weights associated with values of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with an ex termly large datfarem. Here is a sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'Y'], 
})
 ID
0  A
1  A
2  A
3  X
4  X
5  Y
```

Now, given the frequency of each value in column '''ID''', I want to calculate a weight using the function below and add a column that has the weight associated with each value in '''ID'''.

```
def get_weights_inverse_num_of_samples(label_counts, power=1.):
    no_of_classes = len(label_counts)
    weights_for_samples = 1.0/np.power(np.array(label_counts), power)
    weights_for_samples = weights_for_samples/ np.sum(weights_for_samples)*no_of_classes
    return weights_for_samples

freq = df.value_counts()
print(freq)
ID
A     3
X     2
Y     1

weights = get_weights_inverse_num_of_samples(freq)
print(weights)
[0.54545455 0.81818182 1.63636364]
```

So, I am looking for an efficient way to get a dataframe like this given the above weights:

```
   ID  sample_weight
0  A   0.54545455
1  A   0.54545455
2  A   0.54545455
3  X   0.81818182
4  X   0.81818182
5  Y   1.63636364
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you rely on duck-typing a little bit more, you can rewrite your function to return the same input type as outputted.

This will save you of needing to explicitly reaching back into the `.index` prior to calling `.map`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'Y'})

def get_weights_inverse_num_of_samples(label_counts, power=1):
    """Using object methods here instead of coercing to numpy ndarray"""

    no_of_classes = len(label_counts)
    weights_for_samples = 1 / (label_counts ** power)
    return weights_for_samples / weights_for_samples.sum() * no_of_classes

# select the column before using `.value_counts()`
#   this saves us from ending up with a `MultiIndex` Series
freq = df['ID'].value_counts() 

weights = get_weights_inverse_num_of_samples(freq)

print(weights)
# A    0.545455
# X    0.818182
# Y    1.636364

# note that now our weights are still a `pd.Series` 
#  that we can align directly against our `"ID"` column

df['sample_weight'] = df['ID'].map(weights)

print(df)
#   ID  sample_weight
# 0  A       0.545455
# 1  A       0.545455
# 2  A       0.545455
# 3  X       0.818182
# 4  X       0.818182
# 5  Y       1.636364
```

Comment: Quack quack! +1

Answer (score 6):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values:

```
df['sample_weight'] = df['ID'].map(dict(zip(freq.index.get_level_values(0), weights)))
```

*NB. `value_counts` returns a MultiIndex with a single level, thus the needed [`get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html).*

As noted by @ScottBoston, a better approach would be to use:

```
freq = df['ID'].value_counts()

df['sample_weight'] = df['ID'].map(dict(zip(freq.index, weights)))
```

Output:

```
  ID  sample_weight
0  A       0.545455
1  A       0.545455
2  A       0.545455
3  X       0.818182
4  X       0.818182
5  Y       1.636364
```

Comment: I was just about to post this same solutions, I spent an extra few second deciphering why we had a multiindex in the first place.  +1 `dict(zip(df['ID'].value_counts().index, weights))`

Comment: @Scott yes, it's actually a better one!

Comment: @mozway from the df.value_counts docs: "The returned Series will have a MultiIndex with one level per input column". `freq = df["ID"].value_counts()` returns a normal index

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs oh.. he knows that.

Comment: I should have known... ;)

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Yes, I meant, why OP used `value_counts` on the full frame

Comment: @mozway. In this case why don't modify the function and `return dict(zip(label_counts.index, weights_for_samples))`?

Comment: @mozway is there a better way that value_counts() method?

Comment: @armin `value_counts` is fine, just use it on the desired column ;)

Comment: @ScottBoston. What is the most performant: `df['ID'].value_counts()` or `df.value_counts('ID')`?

Comment: @Corralien Great question.... let me run a few test and see.  I suspect the first is by far more performant.

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100000000).reshape(-1, 10), columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])`  `df.value_counts('B')` took 4s and `df['B'].value_counts()` took 785 ms.

Comment: @Corralien yes, I actually had modified the function originally and then thought that maybe OP needed a list, but for sure if this is not the case, returning a Series would be a good idea ;)

Comment: @ScottBoston. Thanks for the answer and I understand why. Try `import dis; dis.dis(df.value_counts); dis.dis(df['ID'].value_counts)`

Comment: @Corralien Wow!  This is the first time seeing the dis library.  Thank you!